# Me encontre con un problema haciendo una plantilla para Wordpress con un If while de php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, php7, wordpress-theme

Hola comunidad tengo un problema, me solicitaron crear un blog para ser administrado por wordpress, entonces recurrí a crear una plantilla según el diseño que me dieron y importarla al wordpress.

Ya todo se ve bien pero hay un detalle que ellos quieren, y es que la estructura de la previsualización de la entrada de blog cambie cada fila, es decir; en la primer fila que sea Imagen y al lado texto, pero en la segunda fila que se primero texto y después imagen.. adjunto imagen del diseño que hicieron:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente en el código de php del index, donde ya se encuentra listando las entradas en dos columnas:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <!-- Blog -->
          <section>
            <div class="row">
              <?php
              query_posts(array(
                "showposts" => 4,
                "cat" => 4
              ));
              ?>
              <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                  <div class="row contentBlog">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                      <a href="#" class="image featured">
                        <?php
                        // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                          the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb-blog');
                        }
                        ?>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 cuerpoBlog">
                      <header>
                        <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                      </header>
                      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                      <footer>
                        <ul class="actions">

                          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
                                 class="buttonLeer">Leer Más</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </footer>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
              <!-- post navigation -->
            <?php else: ?>
              <!-- no posts found -->
              <p>Ups!! no existe nada para esta categoria</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La plantilla la estoy trabajando en html con bootstrap y php. Muchas gracias al que me pueda ayudar hacer esa condición para que se vea igual que el diseño de arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es que crees un contador y hagas este proceso. Creamos un contador ($cnt=1) que cuando el valor es 1 o 2 crea las columnas imagen-texto, y cuando el valor es 3 o 4 crea las columnas texto-imagen. Una vez ha creado las 4 noticias, reseteamos el contador y se repite el proceso en el caso que haya más noticias.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): $cnt=1; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ($cnt == 1 || $cng == 2): ?>

        // Primeras dos noticias con imagen a la izquierda y texto a la derecha
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">IMG</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">TEXTO</div>

    <?php else: ?>

        // Las otras dos noticias con texto a la izquierda y imagen a la derecha
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">TEXTO</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">IMG</div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    // reseteamos el contador una vez haya creado la cuarta noticia
    <?php $cnt++; if ($cnt > 4): $cnt=1; endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Otra cosa que he visto a nivel de diseño son los márgenes entre columnas, esto lo puedes solucionar con la clase 'no-gutters' de Boostrap, así quedarán cómo en el disseño.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho tu recomendación solo hice unos pequeños cambios para que funcionara.
este en el if
<?php if ($cnt == 1 || $cnt==2): ?>

y este en el reseteo del contador
<?php $cnt++; if ($cnt > 4): $cnt=1; endif; ?>

Comment: Cierto, edito la respuesta para que quede constancia.